# Next JS compiling issue mutable globals cannot be exported

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm, next.js

```
Failed to compile.

./assets/images/cross.png
CompileError: AsyncCompile: Wasm decoding failed: mutable globals cannot be exported @+482


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at nextBuildSpan.traceAsyncFn (/var/app/kv-v2/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:924)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! kv-update@1.7.3 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I am getting this error when trying to **npm run build** on my ubuntu server it was working fine previously and it is still compiling fine on my localhost windows machine so to be sure it was not due to my code I reverted to the old copy from Github that was working but its still getting the same error when compiling. I did remove the node_modules and reinstalled.

I tried Googling and there were around 10 articles of this none of them were able to fix my issue. Please help me. Thank you. This is the full log file.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v10.19.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle kv-update@1.7.3~prebuild: kv-update@1.7.3
6 info lifecycle kv-update@1.7.3~build: kv-update@1.7.3
7 verbose lifecycle kv-update@1.7.3~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle kv-update@1.7.3~build: PATH: /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/app/kv-v2/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle kv-update@1.7.3~build: CWD: /var/app/kv-v2
10 silly lifecycle kv-update@1.7.3~build: Args: [ '-c', 'next build' ]
11 silly lifecycle kv-update@1.7.3~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle kv-update@1.7.3~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: kv-update@1.7.3 build: `next build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid kv-update@1.7.3
15 verbose cwd /var/app/kv-v2
16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-109-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.19.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error kv-update@1.7.3 build: `next build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the kv-update@1.7.3 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "kvr",
  "version": "1.7.3",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 4000",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notbaldrick/react-crossfade-carousel": "^1.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.13.1",
    "fathom-client": "^3.1.0",
    "jsonp": "^0.2.1",
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.17.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-facebook-pixel": "^1.0.4",
    "react-img-carousel": "^2.1.1",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.19",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.13.1",
    "eslint": "7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did fix it by removing the cross.png file converting it to cross.jpg and updated the code everything it is importing this file. Strange bug It seems.